# PyMongo aggregation no result

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I try to query the average of 'clicks' from MongoDB database using PyMongo.

```
query_result = list(my_collection.aggregate([{'$group' : {'_id' : None, 'avg_clicks': {'$avg' : "$clicks"}}}]))
```

The result of the query is:

```
ok
result
```

Do you know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Collection.aggregate`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) returns a dictionary like

```
{'ok': 1 or 0, 'result': the_actual_result}
```

Thus

```
list(my_collection.aggregate(...))
```

iterates over the dictionary, getting the list of keys `['ok', 'result']`.